# Regroup By Quarters in Google Sheets

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, week-number

I have two rows in Google Sheets :

Row 3 YYYY-MM (Month) number
Row 5 YYYY-WW (Week) number

[image]

I want to regroup them by quarter, I have put one "ideal solution" and one alternative solution.

[image]

Is there any way I can do this in Google sheets?

here's the example

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mrOrBDCz5goV6E-MRWZifWy2dET63qEMSPD2AUvcsw4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: row 3 and row 5 are manual inputs? whats row 6? attempt?

Comment: Sorry row 6 is solved, no issues here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get Quarters like:

```
=INDEX(TEXT(B3:O3, "yyyy-\Q"&VLOOKUP(MONTH(B3:O3), {1,1;4,2;7,3;10,4}, 2)))
```

[image]

for week numbers use:

```
=INDEX(TEXT(C3:P3, "yyyy-"&TEXT(WEEKNUM(C3:P3, 1), "00")))
```

Comment: Thanks yes so for Months it works perfectly about weeks?